# I am getting a error in spring jpa column Part_Category not found exception can some body help me

Tags: spring, jpa, exception, mysql-error-1064

@Query(value=" select DISTINCT sb.Failed_Part_Number,sb.Replacement_Part_Number,sb.Part_Description  FROM tbl_servicebom sb WHERE sb.Part_Category=:partcatagory", nativeQuery=true)

List findBySpaModel(String partcatagory);

Comment: Do you have the column "Part_Category" in specific schema in your database table?. Post the full stack trace of the exception

Answer (score 0):

One thing that caused this issue could be the mismatch in variable name, check sb.Part_Category if the same name exists in your entity if exists then check for spelling and case sensitivity.